# Specify which pytest tests to run from a file

Tags: python, pytest

How do I select which `pytest` tests to run from a file?

For example, a file `foo.txt` containing a list of tests to be executed:

```
tests_directory/foo.py::test_001
tests_directory/bar.py::test_some_other_test
```

Similarly,

- Is there a way to select multiple tests, having no common pattern in test name, from different directories with pytest?
  `pytest -k <pattern>` allows a single pattern.
  One option is to have a `pytest.mark` against each test, but my requirement is to run different combination of tests from different files.
- Is there a way to specify multiple patterns and a test file name for each pattern?
- Is there a way to specify the exact test paths in a file and feed that file as an input to `pytest`?
- Is there a hook function that can be utilized for this purpose?

Comment: How to exactly filter some test cases in class class01, and some other test cases in class class02 ?

Answer (score 708):

You can use [`-k` option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#using-k-expr-to-select-tests-based-on-their-name) to run test cases with different patterns:

```
py.test tests_directory/foo.py tests_directory/bar.py -k 'test_001 or test_some_other_test'
```

This will run test cases with name **test_001** and **test_some_other_test** deselecting the rest of the test cases.

> Note: This will select any test case starting with **test_001 or test_some_other_test**. For example, if you have test case **test_0012** it will also be selected.

Comment: Thanks. But if there's a test with the same name in foo.py and bar.py (say test_001), it'll end up executing from both.

Comment: yes it will, any thing that matches the pattern will be executed as i have mentioned in the Note

Comment: But that's a problem for me. I'd like to choose which tests to execute from which file.

Comment: btw if you are using PyCharm, you can specify keywords in run configuration of a test

Comment: what will happen if I put test_xxx function in a class called 'TestClass'?

Answer (score 455):

## Specifying tests / selecting tests

Pytest supports several ways to run and select tests from the command-line.

### Run tests in a module

`pytest test_mod.py`

### Run tests in a directory

`pytest testing/`

### Run tests by keyword expressions

`pytest -k "MyClass and not method"`

This will run tests which contain names that match the given string expression, which can include Python operators that use filenames, class names and function names as variables. The example above will run `TestMyClass.test_something` but not `TestMyClass.test_method_simple`.

### Run tests by node ids

Each collected test is assigned a unique `nodeid` which consist of the module filename followed by specifiers like class names, function names and parameters from parametrization, separated by `::` characters.

### To run a specific test within a module:

`pytest test_mod.py::test_func`

Another example specifying a test method in the command line:

`pytest test_mod.py::TestClass::test_method`

### Run tests by marker expressions

`pytest -m slow`

Will run all tests which are decorated with the `@pytest.mark.slow` decorator.

For more information see [marks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/mark.html#mark).

### Run tests from packages

`pytest --pyargs pkg.testing`

This will import `pkg.testing` and use its filesystem location to find and run tests from.

Source: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests

Comment: This is a much better answer than the one above

Comment: How to exactly filter some test cases in class class01, and some other test cases in class class02 ?

Comment: This worked for me while "-k" flag did not.

Answer (score 191):

My answer provides a ways to run a subset of test in different scenarios.

#### Run all tests in a project

```sh
pytest
```

#### Run tests in a Single Directory

To run all the tests from one directory, use the directory as a parameter to
`pytest`:

```sh
pytest tests/my-directory
```

#### Run tests in a Single Test File/Module

To run a file full of tests, list the file with the relative path as a parameter to `pytest`:

```sh
pytest tests/my-directory/test_demo.py
```

#### Run a Single Test Function

To run a single test function, add `::` and the test function name:

```sh
pytest -v tests/my-directory/test_demo.py::test_specific_function
```

`-v` is used so you can see which function was run.

#### Run a Single Test Class

To run just a class, do like we did with functions and add `::`, then the class name to the file parameter:

```sh
pytest -v tests/my-directory/test_demo.py::TestClassName
```

#### Run a Single Test Method of a Test Class

If you don't want to run all of a test class, just one method, just add
another `::` and the method name:

```sh
pytest -v tests/my-directory/test_demo.py::TestClassName::test_specific_method
```

#### Run a Set of Tests Based on Test Name

The `-k` option enables you to pass in an expression to run tests that have
certain names specified by the expression as a substring of the test name.
It is possible to use *and*, *or*, and *not* to create complex expressions.

For example, to run all of the functions that have _raises in their name:

```sh
pytest -v -k _raises
```

Comment: Interestingly it seems that some of these extend to parameterised tests, e.g. if your test runs under the name `test_demo.py::test_function[test_parameters_1]` then you can give this on the command line to just run this parameter instance.

Comment: How to exactly filter some test cases in class class01, and some other test cases in class class02 ?

Answer (score 71):

**Method 1**: Randomly selected tests. Long and ugly.

```
python -m pytest test/stress/test_performance.py::TestPerformance::test_continuous_trigger test/integration/test_config.py::TestConfig::test_valid_config
```

**Method 2: Use Keyword Expressions.**

**Note:** I am searching by testcase names. Same is applicable to TestClass names.

**Case 1:** The below will run whichever is found. Since we have used 'OR' .

```
python -m pytest -k 'test_password_valid or test_no_configuration'
```

Lets say the two above are actually correct, 2 tests will be run.

**Case 2:** Now an incorrect name and another correct name.

```
python -m pytest -k 'test_password_validzzzzzz or test_no_configuration'
```

Only one is found and run.

**Case 3**: If you want to run either all tests mentioned, or None, then use AND

```
python -m pytest -k 'test_password_valid and test_no_configuration'
```

Both will be run if correct or none.

**Case 4:** Run test only in one folder:

```
python -m pytest test/project1/integration -k 'test_password_valid or test_no_configuration'
```

**Case 5:** Run test from only one file.

```
python -m pytest test/integration/test_authentication.py -k 'test_password_expiry or test_incorrect_password'
```

**Case 6:** Run all tests except the match.

```
python -m pytest test/integration/test_authentication.py -k 'not  test_incorrect_password'
```

**Case 7:** Run a test case inside a test class.
This situation arises when the test case name is common and we want to run it for a particular test class only. We can combine test class and test name with keywords.

```
python -m pytest -k "TestClassSomeFeature and test_valid_events"
```

Answer (score 27):

If you have the same method name in two different classes and you just want to run one of them, this works:

```
pytest tests.py -k "TestClassName and test_method_name"
```

Answer (score 22):

According to the doc about Run tests by node ids

since you have all node ids in foo.txt, just run

```
pytest $(tr '\n' ' ' <foo.txt)
```

this is same with below command (with file content in the question)

```
pytest tests_directory/foo.py::test_001 tests_directory/bar.py::test_some_other_test
```

Comment: This is awesome. But in my case, I have a list of test node ids to be skipped written in a text file one line per node id, how can I tell pytest to run a test.py but skip those in my file?

Comment: @StayFoolish https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/pythoncollection.html?highlight=deselect#deselect-tests-during-test-collection

Answer (score 10):

Maybe using `pytest_collect_file()` hook you can parse the content of a `.txt` o `.yaml` file where the tests are specify as you want, and return them to the pytest core.

A nice example is shown in the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/nonpython.html#a-basic-example-for-specifying-tests-in-yaml-files). I think what you are looking for.

Comment: amazing how this is the only relevant answer

Comment: In my case, of having a very long list of specific tests (bigger then what the command line can get) this option might be the best one

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```sh
pytest path/file_test.py::test_name
```

Using `-k` as others have suggested will match any test with that substring, not just a specific test.

Answer (score 8):

Say for example you have a file called `test.py`. In this file you have a class called `TestSomeService`. This class has 2 functions namely `test_service1` and `test_service2`.

1. Now to run specific function test you can this

- `pytest test.py::TestSomeService::test_service1`
- `pytest test.py::TestSomeService::test_service2`

2. To run specific class

- `pytest test.py::TestSomeService`

Comment: I don't understand why no one recommended of doing that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Here's a possible partial answer, because it only allows selecting the test scripts, not individual tests within those scripts.

And it also limited by my using legacy compatibility mode vs `unittest` scripts, so not guaranteeing it would work with native pytest.

Here goes:

1. create a new dictory, say `subset_tests_directory`.
2. `ln -s tests_directory/foo.py`
3. `ln -s tests_directory/bar.py`
4. be careful about imports which implicitly assume files are in `test_directory`.  I had to fix several of those by running `python foo.py`, from within `subset_tests_directory` and correcting as needed.
5. Once the test scripts execute correctly, just `cd subset_tests_directory` and `pytest` there.  Pytest will only pick up the scripts it sees.

Another possibility is symlinking within your current test directory, say as `ln -s foo.py subset_foo.py` then `pytest subset*.py`.  That would avoid needing to adjust your imports, but it would clutter things up until you removed the symlinks.  Worked for me as well.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the test names are unique, you have to remove the test file's name:

```
cut -d : -f 3 foo.txt > FAILED_TESTS.txt
```

As others pointed out use `-k`, but you have to pass the file's content (i.e., list of test names) as a single string:

```
pytest -k "$(awk '$1=$1' RS= OFS=' or '  FAILED_TESTS.txt)"
```

`awk` will replace the new lines with a delimiter  `or`  so that the test names are joined in a format that pytest expects.