# How do we test a specific method written in a list of files for functional testing in python

Tags: python, testing, pytest

The project has so many modules. There are functional test cases being written for almost every api written like for GET requests, POST requests and PUT requests. To test an individual file we use the syntact pytest tests/file_name.py
but I want to test a specific method in that file. Is there any way to test it like that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [Is there a way to specify which pytest tests to run from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456920/is-there-a-way-to-specify-which-pytest-tests-to-run-from-a-file)

In a few words, you can use the -k option of pytest to specify the name of the test you would like to run.

Comment: So in my case , there are some methods like test_login_user_successful(),test_login_user_unsuccessful(),test_refresh_successful(),get_username() in test_users.py file. I want to test  get_username() method. How would that be tested

Comment: Have you tried:
`pytest tests/file_name.py -k 'test_get_username'`
?

I wonder if your issue isn't the missing prefix for your test. All pytest's tests MUST be preceded by 'test_' otherwise it's not concidered as a test.

Comment: If your tests are enclosed in a test suite class, use `pytest tests/file_name.py -k '<YourTestClass>.test_get_username'`

Comment: Yes issue is that I havent mentioned test as a prefix!! My bad!