# How to use a specific method for py.test?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to use a specific method to be run using `py.test`, and I have seen several suggestions like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456920/is-there-a-way-to-specify-which-pytest-tests-to-run-from-a-file) and [HERE](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/usage.html), but for some reasons these answers do not work.

I have a file `mytest.py` which has a method `special_test` which I want to start with `py.test`. And neither

```
py.test mytest.py::special_test
```

nor

```
py.test mytest.py -k special_test
```

do work.

In the first example I get an `ERROR: not found` and in the second example it just says `no tests ran`.

What am I missing here?

Content of `mytest.py`:

```
def special_test():
    assert True
```

Comment: By default, test functions have to start with `test_`, otherwise they won't be recognized as a test (this [can be changed](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/pythoncollection.html?highlight=discovery#changing-naming-conventions), though). As an aside: using `py.test` is long deprecated, use `pytest` instead.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen This information seems to be missing from the linked documentation. However, how to run a test with a method that does NOT start with `test_`?

Comment: As shown in the linked documentation, you have to adapt your `pytest.ini` (for example by setting `python_files = *.py`).

Comment: As for the doucmentation - it is [there](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery), but not easy to find if you don't know where to look. This could certainly be linked from the usage part...